# denoting optional parameters via annotations for phpstan

Tags: php, phpstan

I have a class that has a `__call` method. The first parameter to the `__call` method, per the PHP docs, is the method name. If the method name is unsupported I throw an exception.

The problem with this is that if I do `vendor/bin/phpstan analyze test.php --level=9`, where test.php is a file that calls a method that ultimately invokes `__call`, then PHPStan will give a `Call to an undefined method MyClass::myFunction().` error.

The way to workaround this is, as I understand it, is to add  `* @method mixed myFunction(string $a, int $b)` in the DocBlock comment at the top of the class. But what if the second parameter is optional? eg. what if the second parameter has a default argument value (to use the terminology from https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php). How would I denote that for PHPStan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what if the second parameter has a default argument value. How would I denote that for PHPStan?

Same way as with normal PHP code:

```php
* @method mixed myFunction(string $a, int $b = 123)
```

On-line playground link: https://phpstan.org/r/06f85674-b0c4-4dc7-935b-9dfa3196456e